# Cannot launch AVD in emulator in Android studio in ubuntu

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am using Android Studio 2.1.2. Operating system is Ubuntu 14.

I created an emulator using the image arm. When i started the emulator, I got the error as

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator.

Output:

> PANIC: `HOME` is defined but could not find `Nexus_4_API_23.ini` file in
>   `$HOME/.android/avd`
>
> (Note: avd is searched in the order of
>   `$ANDROID_AVD_HOME`,`$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd` and
>   `$HOME/.android/avd`)".

Comment: Check if virtualization is enabled in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in Xubuntu 16.04. I initially installed as the root user which caused the issue.

The Studio keeps looking for the avd path in your $HOME directory but it's actually in /root/.android/avd.  You CAN copy the avd folder to your home dir but you may run into permission issues.

So I "reinstalled" under my current user which fixed it, these are the steps:

- Delete the .android folder under *~/.android*
- Move the unzipped android-studio folder to /usr/local/.
- Add the /usr/local/android-studio/bin to the PATH variable.
- To permanently save it add it to your .bash_profile (or ~/.profile) file as:

  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/android-studio/bin
- Now you can run it in the terminal as *studio.sh*
- Run studio.sh and re-configure Android Studio.
- Rebuild your virtual device and try running it again.

That worked for me, hopefully it works for you.